# Updating ArrayList with servlets n jsp

Tags: java, servlets

Sir i have an issue of updating my array list connected wd jsp n action servlet along wd form bean..

here is my frst jsp page where i m displaying the list:i want to update this list wd servlet where roll no will be the condition do help??

```
<%Iterator itr;%>
<% ArrayList data= (ArrayList)request.getAttribute("data");
    for (itr=data.iterator(); itr.hasNext(); )
    {


%>
    <tr>

        <td width="40"> <input type="text" value="<%=itr.next()%>"/></td>
        <td width="40"><input type="text"  name="th2" value="<%=itr.next()%>"/></td>
            <td width="40"><input type="text"  value="<%=itr.next()%>"/></td>
    <td width="40"><input type="text"  value="<%=itr.next()%>"/></td>
            <td width="40"><input type="text"  value="<%=itr.next()%>"/></td>
            <td width="40"><input type="text"  value="<%=itr.next()%>"/></td>

</tr>
<%}%>
```

Comment: (1) [Avoid Scriptlets in JSP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files) (2) you are calling `.next()` so many times inside the loop ! (3) Your question is not clear , please elaborate on the flow.

Comment: ok forget dis code just help me wd dis how can i update table which has name and marks along wd roll no?
My aim is to update the table keeping rollno as primary key

Comment: Whyere do you want to update ? DB or inside the JSP page itself ?

Comment: The new values should get store in db

Comment: Then  you need to send the values to the server side , submit a form using `POST` or make an ajax call .

Comment: ok bt hw will i store loop values for eg there will be many names?should i use array for dat?

Comment: You can use JSON ....

Comment: i m sorry bt wts that ??

Comment: Instead of asking me , google it , your requirement is very basic , you will get lots of examples in net , you can type JSON in net and you will get tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

That is not how an iterator works.  iter.hasNext specifies whether there are more elements.  iter.next advances to the next.  You are calling hasNext once, but next 6 times.

You are essentially asking: "Do you have a first element?  If so, get me the first 6."  But you may only have 2 elements and that will cause an IndexOutOfBoundsException.

The foreach loop syntax automatically fetches an iterator for you so it reduces your code.

Try this:

```
<% for (Object o : (ArrayList)request.getAttribute("data"))
   {
%>
    <tr>

        <td width="40"> <input type="text" value="<%=o %>"/></td>
        <td width="40"><input type="text"  name="th2" value="<%=o %>"/></td>
        <td width="40"><input type="text"  value="<%=o %>"/></td>
        <td width="40"><input type="text"  value="<%=o %>"/></td>
        <td width="40"><input type="text"  value="<%=o %>"/></td>
        <td width="40"><input type="text"  value="<%=o %>"/></td>

</tr>
<% } %>
```

Comment: Thanks for dis its showing data perfectly bt the main issue is hw can i update the values specified in the table i m not able to understand that

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: ok forget dis code just help me wd dis how can i update table which has name and marks along wd roll no? My aim is to update the table keeping rollno as primary key